# iOS SDK: AudioQueue and AirPlay

Tags: ios, airplay, audioqueueservices

I'm currently investigating how we could add airplay functionality to our existing application.

In this app, we're using AudioQueue "manually". We're not using AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayer. So we're just pushing audio buffers into an AudioQueue and play sound.

Point is: how can I use airplay with an AudioQueue? As far as I can see, we need to use HTTP streaming and one of AVPlayer or MPMoviePlayer.

**tl;dr How can I use airplay if I push audio buffers to an audio queue myself.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the answer is: there's just nothing to do.

You may want to populate data into `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`, but really that's all you got to do. Enjoy !